# Immersed isometrically in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, curvature

I know well that there is an isometric immersion of the hyperbolic plane in $\mathbb R^5$ due to *Rozendorn* and that the hyperbolic plane cannot be immersed isometrically in $\mathbb R^3$ due to *Hilbert*, also I think that the problem in $\mathbb R^4$ is still open. So questions arise that I can't answer:

1. Are there surfaces with negative Gaussian curvature immersed isometrically in $\mathbb R^4$?
2. Are there surfaces with negative Gaussian curvature with $K\leq const<0$ immersed isometrically in $\mathbb R^4$?
3. Are there surfaces with constant negative Gaussian curvature immersed isometrically in $\mathbb R^4$?

Does anyone know where I can read more about the existence of complete surfaces with constant Gaussian curvature -1 immersed isometrically in $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: Just a small correction. In view of the pseudosphere, please add “complete” to your Hilbert discussion.

Comment: Yes, I'm taking the complete hyperbolic plane as otherwise I would have put a *part of the hyperbolic plane* which is immersed isometrically in $\mathbb R^3$ represented as the pseudosphere, for example.

Comment: If you're OK with lower regularity maps, you can upgrade them to isometric embeddings, by Nash-Kuiper. You start by embedding your surface any old way by the hard Whitney theorem, and then use this result to find a nearby isometric embedding which is $C^1$. I wouldn't be surprised if some of these questions were open otherwise though.